# Issue in parsing jdbc call procedure output unresolvedResultSets

Tags: tibco-business-works

I am trying to read the output of JDBC call procedure and parse it and map it to next activity,

I created a schema similar to output received in unresolvedResultSets, and placed parseXML after JDBC call procedure.

When I run it, I can see output in parseXML, (I have uncheked validate output),

and then I map the element ResultSets\resuletSet1\Record1\ID to mapper.
However, its not able to read the ID from output of parseXML and passes empty value as input.

what could be the problem?
It seems such a simple task,  still I amstuck due to some silly issue.
What Am i missing here?

Pls help

thanks,
Gopal

I tried passing mapping element as ResultSets\resuletSet1[1]\Record1[1]\ID, still samwe issue

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625153/how-to-parse-unresolved-result-set-in-tibco-bw-jdbc-palette/49201325#49201325

Answer (score 0):

You need to create schema like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xsd:element name="Resultsets">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="ResultSet1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Record1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="PROCEDURE_OUTPUT_COLUMN1" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="PROCEDURE_OUTPUT_COLUMN2" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="PROCEDURE_OUTPUT_COLUMN2" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Please note that elements names "PROCEDURE_OUTPUT_COLUMN1", "PROCEDURE_OUTPUT_COLUMN2" ... should be exact same as procedure output names.

procedure example (ORACLE)

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE "GET_COLUMNS" (

            p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR

            ) AS

             sql_stmt   VARCHAR2 (32600);


            BEGIN
              sql_stmt :=

              BEGIN
                 OPEN p_recordset FOR sql_stmt;
              EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
                p_sql := 'ERROR in the SQL statment: ' || sql_stmt;
              END;

            END GET_COLUMNS;
```

Then you can map procedure output to the ParseXML

You may also need to use native database driver instead of tibco driver for better performance

Please also see the [How to parse unresolved result set in Tibco BW JDBC palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625153/how-to-parse-unresolved-result-set-in-tibco-bw-jdbc-palette/49201325#49201325)

for other more advanced options